# to source the data from Athena or Redshift to Sage maker or AWS Forecast instead of the flat file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to source the data from Athena or Redshift to Sage maker or AWS Forecast directly without using the flat data. In Sage maker I use Jupyter Notebook python code. Is there anyway to do so without even connecting to S3.

So far I have been using flat data which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SageMaker you have to use S3 to read data, SageMaker does not read data from Redshift, but will be able to read data from Athena using PyAthena.

If your data source is in Redshift you need to load your data to S3 first to be able to use in SageMaker. If you are using Athena your data is already in S3.

Amazon Machine Learning used to support reading data from Redshift or RDS but unfortunately it's not available any more.

Comment: Note if your data is "in athena", it probably is in S3.

Comment: You are right, I'll rephrase it to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

if you're only using a SageMaker notebook instance, your data doesn't have to be in S3. You can use the boto3 SDK or a SQL connection (depending on the backend) to download data, store it locally, and work on it in your notebook.

If you're using the SageMaker SDK to train, then yes, data must be in S3. You can either do this manually if you're experimenting, or use services like AWS Glue or AWS Batch to automate your data pipeline.

Indeed, Athena data is probably already in S3, although it may be in a format that your SageMaker training code doesn't support. Creating a new table with the right SerDe (say, CSV) may be enough. If not, you can certainly get the job done with AWS Glue or Amazon EMR.

When it comes to Redshift, dumping CSV data to S3 is as easy as:

```
unload ('select * from mytable')   
to 's3://mybucket/mytable' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
delimiter ',';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[SageMaker Data Wrangler](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/data-wrangler/) now allows you to read data directly from Amazon Redshift. But I'm not sure if you can from across AWS accounts (e.g. if you had one account for dev and another account for prod)